# Unable to connect to remote host: Connection timed out when trying to telnet to MySQL?

Tags: mysql, connection, telnet

When trying to connect to mysql server via telnet I am getting following error:

```
telnet localhost 3306
Trying ::1...
Trying 127.0.0.1...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection timed out
```

I tried telnet with 127.0.0.1, `hostname` also, but getting same error message. But I can connect with `mysql -u username -p` once I am in the server.

Here is the result of netstat:

```
netstat -na | grep mysql
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     4540495  /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

netstat -na | grep 3306
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3306            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
```

What could be possible problems? If you need some more details I could provide it without any problems.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Are you able to provide the output of iptables-save? Can you also try to telnet to the host using the non-localhost IP address of the machine (so, for example 192.168.1.1)?

Answer (score 3):

Can you connect with:

```
mysql -h127.0.0.1 -u username -p
```

If not, check whether your server was started 'skip-networking' enabled:

> If the server was started with --skip-networking, it will not accept TCP/IP connections at all. [src](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/can-not-connect-to-server.html)

Which indicates 127.0.0.1 will not work, but localhost will. In mysql localhost and 127.0.0.1 are different hosts.

Further things to check:

- are you running the default port (3306)? Check your my.cnf or do `mysqladmin -h localhost -p variables | grep port`
- > If you are running under Linux and Security-Enhanced Linux (SELinux) is enabled, make sure you have disabled SELinux protection for the mysqld process.

Comment: mysql -h localhost -u username -p works fine but mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -u username -p says ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (110)

Comment: How to see whether it is started with --skip-networking or not?

Comment: If you log in on localhost, do `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'skip_networking'`

Comment: I have ubuntu and have revised my.cnf for skip-networking parameter. I didn't find any record saying skip-networking.

Comment: SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'skip_networking' is showing skip_networking | OFF   |

Comment: I added a few other things to check

Comment: Yeah, it is running on 3306. But don't know any idea of SELinux. How do I get that? Thanks a lot for help.

Comment: Hey DTest, have Bakhtiyor try `mysql -h127.0.0.1 --protocol=tcp -u username -p` to force TCP/IP protocol

Answer (score 1):

I got same problem and i resolved . I use Mac pro & sequel Pro as mysql client , socket localhost connection succeeded but standard tcp/ip Connection failed!
and I check my running port by using cmd :

```
mysqladmin -h localhost -u root -p variables | grep port
```

here is my result status:

```
wangxiaodeMacBook-Pro:~ wangxiao$ mysqladmin -h localhost -u root -p variables | grep port
Enter password: 
| innodb_support_xa                                      | ON                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               |
| large_files_support                                    | ON                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               |
| port                                                   | 3307                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             |
| report_host                                            |                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  |
| report_password                                        |                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  |
| report_port                                            | 3307                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             |
| report_user                                            |
```

It's porting 3307 not default 3306 , there was another mysql server installed once .
so change it and resolved.  tks @DTest 's answer.

Comment: Welcome to ServerFault. Thank you posting your answer ; although it does not really add al that much  more to the already existing answer, especially without proper formatting. To show appreciation please  vote up any useful answer and not just say thank you.  Hope you stay around will become another active community member.